# Crawling a members-only page with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i want to get data from a forum page with requests and BeautifulSoup modules.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

src = requests.get("http://forum.bazicenter.com/members/59765/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src)

for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'im_txt_link'}):
   mail = link.string
   print(mail)
```

The problem is that accessing this page needs to be logged in first.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Go with Jivan's answer, Using requests.Session() automatically handles cookies, the only difference is that you must continue working with the session object to make requests.

Comment: there are numerous questions related to what you want to do, a simple search would return all the information you need.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I agree but running into the hidden inputs in an HTML source can be confusing, and many answers don't cover that part. Not saying non do of course, but asking a question that been asked before doesn't hurt. Theirs always someone to help. Instead of telling the OP to dig through hundreds of similar questions, instead how about providing a link to one?

Comment: @Crispy, there is a thing called google and also a  search box on SO that does finds those questions and answers for you, there is not much digging to be done if you actually go and look

Comment: Whatever, if your not here to help the OP, then there really no point in this discussion, almost everyone on planet earth knows the power of the google you speak of, there's not much use telling someone to google their question. Right?

Comment: @Crispy are you the OP?

Comment: No your right, it seems babak doesn't have an opinion, so this is all pointless. I'm still here because of boredom that's it.

Comment: @Crispy, well it was directed at the OP, the request docs are brilliant and there are numerous good answers on SO which a simple search would find, I see no attempt in the OP's code at logging in so it is obvious they have not tried too hard, if someone makes some effort and gets stuck  that is fine but making zero effort is not.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham indeed.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ok we understood that your answer if #rtfm. Is is worth repeating it? :)

Comment: @Jivan,#rtfm is always a good way to start  ;) seriously though the questions on SO are progressively getting worse, you could look all day and not find one interesting question anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Generic answer

Yes. Use `requests.Session()`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

login_data = {'email':'me@example.com', 'password':'pw'}
s.post("http://forum.bazicenter.com/login", login_data)

result = s.get("http://forum.bazicenter.com/members/59765/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(result)
```

[Link to the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects).

Note that you may be compelled to provide a `csrf` token, which you would get by sending a `get` request to the login form first, which you would then crawl to retrieve the token, in order to include it in your `login_data` dictionary.

### Answer for your particular situation

Guessing by the login form, you could use those parameters:

```
login_url = "http://forum.bazicenter.com/login.php?do=login"
login_data = {
    'vb_login_password_hint': 'your_password',
    'vb_login_username': 'username'
}

s.post(login_url, login_data)
```

... but it's going to be tricky, as the site uses a **strange and weird way** of `md5`-hashing the password with JavaScript to put into a hidden password field in the form, before posting it.

If no salt has to be provided, you could try to `md5` the password from Python before posting. You'll have to study how it's done more precisely, though.

Comment: Read my answer for a simply solution to finding the needed parameters, instead of attempting to study the HTML source, because it's a pain and time consuming. Although don't always depend on the simple solution. You should do as Jivan says and learn to study the HTML source later on.

Comment: @Jivan no luck with your way.it must have some kind of salting.

Comment: @babak-1990 instead of saying "no luck with your way", which suggests that it's not the good way, you should be glad that "my way" at least brought you up to this point :)

Comment: @Jivan sorry, i meant no disrespect.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the studying `Jivan` mentioned, you need to know the other parameters to send when making a request. A simple way to do this is to open a browser and proxy the request to your self to see how the login form works.

#### Step 1:

First off, this is using firefox, go into options, then go to the advanced tab, then choice network. From network click on settings, then check the manual radio button.

#### Step2:

Now we can specify where to send the request. Set the `HTTP Proxy` to `127.0.0.1` and the port to `8080`.
Before applying this setting, make sure that the `No Proxy` field at the bottom is empty. That is, not restricting `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Now when you make a request you will get an error page. This is because the request in being sent to you not the website and no response is generated.

#### Code that will print the proxied request.

Here is a python script that will print the request for you. Make sure to run this script before making the request. The parameters are in the line that has a space between it and the larger body of text which is the `header`.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
s.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1 ) # Needed to reuse the script after closing, due to network reasons
s.bind(( '127.0.0.1', 8080 ))
s.listen( 1 )

while True:
    client, client_addr = s.accept()
    
    data = client.recv(4069)
    print data
    
    client.close()

s.close()
```

Comment: When binding sockets, if you don't use the SO_REUSEADDR option then when you close the script and go to re-run it, you will get an error. This is due to a `TIME WAIT` that is forced upon all sockets, unless specified other wise. You will have to wait a few minutes before using that port again.